# Calculating button press time with STM32?

Tags: c, stm32

I'm trying to calculate the time the button was pressed with the STM32F407 Discovery. Frequency can be any value for now. How do I calculate time?
What I am trying to do is; To enable the microcontroller to perform different operations according to different pressing times with two buttons (For example, changing the flashing times of the led). While doing this, I want to press one button for 1 second and the other button for 4 seconds (short - long press). Let the led continue its operation by not leaving the loop during the time I press it. Let it do whatever it takes when you release the button.
Help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide more information about the framework / libraries / tools you are using to program for the STM32 as the answer will depend on it.

Comment: The STM32 probably has a peripheral that counts time. You should be able to set it running with a certain frequency when the program starts up, and then check the current time when the button is pressed and released, and see if the gap is longer than 4 seconds.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: count time in the priodic interrupt

Comment: you could set a ISR for button to both edges - when some changes occures - then you can use TIMER (or just reading actual ticks from system timer - SYSTICK) for measuring time between edges...

Answer (score -1):

you could probably use one of the general purpose timers as enable it when the button is first pressed, then disable it when the button is released? you might need to mess with the ARR and PSC registers to make the CNT register read the button press duration.